# Sonar: Validate changes from a date

Tags: c#, testing, tfs, sonarqube, azure-devops

I use Git integrated with Team Foundation Server. The idea is to put Sonar as a step in TFS to stop the build according to the established rule.
I need to know if it is possible for Sonar to apply the tests only for changes made as of a certain date. Example: I have a 1-year history of system changes. I'm going to put the Sonar step today. I want it to only check the changes made as of today.
To reduce the initial impact, the idea would be to make a validation framework, and then validate what was left behind. It's possible?

Comment: Did you read the [Fix the Water Leak](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Fixing+the+Water+Leak) documentation?

Comment: No. I'll read. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [analysis parameter `sonar.projectDate`](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters), you could use this parameter to assign a date to the analysis.

> **Note**: This parameter is applicable to a few, special use cases, rather than being an "every day" parameter:
>
> - When analyzing a new project, you may want to retroactively create    some history for the project in order to get some information on
>     quality trends over the last few versions.
> - When moving from one database engine to another, it is highly    recommended (even mandatory) to start from a fresh new database
>     schema. In doing so, you will lose the entire history for all your
>     projects. Which is why you may want to feed the new SonarQube
>     database with some historical data.
>
> To answer those use cases, you can use the sonar.projectDate property.
>   The format is yyyy-MM-dd, for example: 2010-12-01.
>
> The process is the following:
>
> - Retrieve the oldest version of your application's source that you    wish to populate into the history (from a specific tag, whatever).
> - Run a SonarQube analysis on this project by setting the          sonar.projectDate property. Example: sonar-scanner
>     -Dsonar.projectDate=2010-12-01
> - Retrieve the next version of the source code of your application,    update the sonar.projectDate property, and run another analysis. And
>     so on for all the versions of your application you're interested in.
>
> Since you cannot perform an analysis dated prior to the most recent
>   one in the database, you must analyze your versions in chronological
>   order, oldest first.